# Android Attachments are not sent by email

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing and android app, and at certain point i want to allow the user to send a .csv file by email. 
I've seen a lot of tutorials in the web, and all of them have the same code, the same code i've tryed many times. The thing is, the send email activity starts, the attachment appears in the email, but when it is sent, the file or goes empty to the destination, or doesn't appear in the destination at all.

Here is some piece of code:

```
File file = null;
File dir = ProjectViewerResume.this.getCacheDir();
if (dir.canWrite()){
    file = new File(dir, ProjectViewerResume.this.mProject.getName()+".csv");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.write(csv.toString().getBytes());
    out.close();
}
Uri u1 = null;

u1 = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Project Resume: "+
                ProjectViewerResume.this.mProject.getName());
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
sendIntent.setType("text/csv");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

The csv variable has file content in csv format.
I've omited the try..catch so the code seems cleaner..

Thks in advance

Comment: You need to remember that the email application can not access files from your apps personal storage, to attach to an email you move your file to a place that the email application can access, like external storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of Email");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/file.csv"));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the mail");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

If some problem occur in attaching file try following path.

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/file.csv"));
```

Comment: Do not hardwire paths. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to identify the root of external storage.

Comment: I«ve already tested the above code, but i still get the an empty attachment...Any ideias?Does the above code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. So not to duplicate the same post I want to show you my code, which is slightly different from yours, but still sends an email with a 0KB attachment.
I print 2 messages to the Log:

The path is printed (I edited the package name)

The size of the file is not 0KB !!!

```
05-11 11:32:58.133: W/Log Viewer(432): Path is /data/data/<package>/files/LogCat.log.gzip
05-11 11:32:58.192: W/Log Viewer(432): The file is 504 bytes
```

I stopped inside the code with the Eclipse debugger and inspected the uriLog: it is not null and contains the right path.

The code is:

```
        public void run() {
            Uri uriLog = null;
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("LogCat.log.gzip", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                out.write(gzip(dump().getBytes()));
                out.close();
                File gzipFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "LogCat.log.gzip");
                //uriLog = Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/LogCat.log.gzip");
                uriLog = Uri.fromFile(gzipFile);
                Log.w(TAG,"Path is " + uriLog.getPath());
                Log.w(TAG,"The file is " + gzipFile.length() + " bytes");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android Log");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dump());
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriLog);
            try {
                String str = getResources().getString(R.string.send_prompt);
                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, str);
                startActivity(chooser);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Things I tried:

I created the uri by parse (see the commented line

I also put the data inside the email body to check it exists --> it arrives in the email

I also tried to put the gziped data in the email body to check it exists --> it arrived in the email


EDIT:

Tried to send a pre-existing file in the emulator, from /mnt/system/app/CustomLocale.apk
 23745 bytes
The path from uriLog.getPath() was printed /apk/CustomLocale.apk
 and the mail still arrived with an attachment named CustomLocale.apk and 0KB size


[image: screenshot from emulator]

The only thing it occurs to me that is failing, is that putextra(intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri) is based on

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Parcelable value)
```

and **uris** implement the parcelable interface. But for some reason, which I will investigate, maybe the call to *writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)* is not writing the file data out; that's why it is 0KB in the attachment.

Comment: I think the problem is that the email client can not access (for security reasons) the path /data/data/<package>/files/LogCat.log.gzip where you have the file. Only your own app can do it.

Try to store it somewhere else where the email client has permission to access.

Answer (score 0):

This code works now for me.
Using createTempFile instead of openFileOutput. I still don't know what was wrong with the former approach.
It attaches a file named **LogCat.log.gzip** which is not empty this time and it has the data I put insde.

```js
        public void run() {
            Uri uriLog = null;
            try {
                File gzipFile = File.createTempFile("LogCat.log", ".gzip");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(gzipFile);
                out.write(gzip(dump().getBytes()));
                out.close();
                uriLog = Uri.fromFile(gzipFile);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android Log");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dump());
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriLog);
            try {
                String str = getResources().getString(R.string.send_prompt);
                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, str);
                startActivity(chooser);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

And don't forget to add this line to your manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```